# Facebook API: list of most liked pages

Tags: php, json, facebook, api

Using the Facebook API, is it possible to get a list of the most liked pages (non Facebook pages) that were liked in a certain time span?

Comment: I was able to get likes from URLs I specified but I don't know how to obtain a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of pages is not available via the Facebook Graph API.  You could scrape their [Page Browser](http://www.facebook.com/pages/browser.php), as it does not require anyone to be logged into Facebook.  It also has an option for pages by country.